# tor keep give me restart

Tags: help

im having problem with tor browser

after it make the connection and it open the browser after 10 to 15 sec it display a massage to me  say:

```
Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not able to reach any websites. If the problem persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team.

9/19/2015 6:19:03 AM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 

9/19/2015 6:19:03 AM.300 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\zoran\Desktop\TORBRO~1\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 

9/19/2015 6:19:03 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 

9/19/2015 6:19:04 AM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 

9/19/2015 6:19:04 AM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 

9/19/2015 6:19:04 AM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 

9/19/2015 6:19:05 AM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus
```

please advise

Comment: I suggest you create a new bug report[here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor)

Comment: Have you edited your `torrc` file at all? If so, can you edit your question to include a copy of it?

Answer (score -1):

You can look into using Bridges.

[Documentation about bridges on the Tor Project web site.](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en)